# Something strange happens with ASP.net resources files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources, localization

Something strange happens to me today.

I’m working on a Multilanguage application using global resources.

I have several files, one for each language. i.e. companies.es.resx, companies.en.resx, etc.
Nothing special or different from any other ordinary Multilanguage app.

Today, the app fail and I traced the problem to be that HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject didn’t find the resource file.

After scratching my head for a while, I remember that yesterday, before I closed my Visual Studio, I delete a resource file that was garbage.  This file was unused and in fact it was empty.

Just for “You never know” I create a new empty resource file, and Walla!!! Everything begins to work perfect again.

The ONLY difference with this file, is that is named without the language like test.resx.
I don’t  get it, It is so weird.

Another funny thing is that when I try to access the resources with “Resources.” Test is the only resource I get.

Any Idea what is happening?

I’m using visual studio 2010 with MVC 3.

Thanks!
Edgar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default resource file (without any language extension like `companies.resx`) is required with other language based files (like `companies.es.resx` or `companies.fr.resx`) when working with resources files for multilingual project.

**Reasons:** When no file exist, matching with the current culture then default file is used by .net. For example you have two language based files

1. `.fr.resx` for French
2. `.es.resx` for Espanish for instance

And if current user's language is other than these for instance `Arabic` then the default resource file will be used. i.e. `.resx` without any specific language extensions.

Comment: Thanks! Thats make so much sense! Now I understand what the no sense error message mean!

Comment: @epaulk, It is recommended that you must include default resource files `resx` and its quite possible that your localized `.es.resx` file has less keys than default `.resx` file

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with resources in VS2010 too. After trying to reference non existing resource in the resources table Visual Studio was crashing. It didn't even let me to correct the wrong reference because it was crashing all the time. 
I fixed this problem by deleting the wrong line in the file with regular text editor and after that running the VS again. 
It seems that VS2010 has some issues with resources.